# How do I set a modern news page template's default Publish Date/Time to the Current Date/Time

Tags: sharepoint-online

When creating a news item in a site collection page's library, we have several custom templates built by a 3rd party. As I understand it, there was a time (before I started working on this tenant) when creating a news article based on one of these custom templates prefilled the "Publish Date and Time" field with the current date and time. However, this has stopped working, and the default values are now static.

I've checked the list content type settings for the "Publish Date and Time" column and I see that it's set to default to "Today's Date." However, that is not reflected in the new page when it's created using a template. Presumably, this is because the news post duplicates the template file, and the template has a static value for "Publish Date Time." Is it possible for me to remove this static value or make some configuration change that will override the static value and replace it with today's date and time?

Right now, the template folder list view looks like this:
[image]

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to use Calculated Value instead of Today's Date in column settings.

List settings > click column to edit > in Default value check Calculated Value and type "=Now()"

[image]

Or Column settings > edit

[image]